# Getting weird bug when running phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

I am working on a project that is made in nodejs and uses mysql, and am using phpmyadmin for the gui. When I work on this project at work it works fine. Essentially when I click a button made in html it will insert an array into a table within a database on my mysql server. I just installed ubuntu on my laptop and had a bit of trouble getting phpmyadmin to work, and ended up trying a bunch of different commands so hopefully that did not screw it up. 
When I run this program at home it does exactly what I want it to. The terminal outputs the desired output and the values within the array do get stored in the database table, the only difference is I get this error from phpmyadmin

```
Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#613
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2079: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'sitepoint',
string 'siblings',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `siblings`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'sitepoint',
string 'siblings',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `siblings`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I will link to my github to show the source code of the project, it is very simple. I really do not think it has anything to do with the code given that I do not get this error at work (when working on a raspberrypi with raspbian) and also given that the program still works properly. I am worried this has come from something dumb I did when installing mysql-server or phpmyadmin.

Comment: Sounds like you should submit a bug report to phpmyadmin

Comment: First, make sure it's an up-to-date version running on a supported version of PHP.